# Providing Git-Repo with Apache SSHD

Tags: java, git, sshd

Is there a way to provide a Git Repository over SSH by using the Apache SSHD library? I am able to provide the file system structure by using **SftpSubsystemFactory** but this doesn't enable the whole functionality which seems to be necessary for the Git commands. If I do it the Linux native way, I need something like the git-shell which does these things, I believe. Is there any equivalent implementation known, maybe for Apache SSHD?